# Why is the ternary operator in the for...of statement not working?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I am not sure why the ternary operator is not working in this example. I have seen it used in similar ways before but I can not get it to work properly in this test. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(includes(numbers, 4));
//This works fine
function includes(array, searchElement) {
    for (let element of array)
        if (element === searchElement)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

This solution works fine but when I try to use the ternary operator I always get false.

```
console.log(includes2(numbers, 4));

function includes2(array, searchElement) {
    for (let element of array) {
        return (element === searchElement ? true : false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your statements are not the same.  Your first block only returns true if the if is true.  And it only returns false once the for loop finishes.  The second snippet **always** returns in the for, no matter what

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I did not know that! :)

Comment: btw, the ternary is just the same returning than the condition.

Comment: Also, since it looks like your find logic is just an identity check, this could be reduced to a simple `indexOf() > -1` check.  Your logic is semi-reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is a great example of why it's a good idea to include the curly-brackets on your `for` and `if` blocks, even if they're not strictly required. This would be a lot easier to spot if you made it explicit where your `for` and `if` each ended.

Comment: I knew about indexOf(). This was an exercise to try to recreate the includes() method. But thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets add blocks and convert the conditional operator back to `if`:

First example:

```
function includes(array, searchElement) {
    for (let element of array) {
        if (element === searchElement) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Second example:

```
function includes2(array, searchElement) {
    for (let element of array) {
        // return (element === searchElement ? true : false);
        if (element === searchElement) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note the position of the `return false;` statement. In the first case you return after the loop. In the second case you return inside the loop, i.e. the function will always terminate in the first iteration of the loop.